# Oracle SQL, group by multiple group by expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

First of all here is the data I'm working with [Data](http://prntscr.com/bajeg8).
What I want to do is for each department display the count of each relationship count:

Dnumber Sons Daughters Spouses

So far I only managed to group by relationship like that

```
SELECT DNUMBER DEPARTMENT_NUMBER , count(d.DNUMBER) DEPENTENT_COUNT 
FROM DEPARTMENT d JOIN employee e ON d.DNUMBER = e.DNO JOIN DEPENDENT de ON de.ESSN = e.SSN
GROUP BY d.DNUMBER;
```

I also try creating views for each relationship type but that didn't work either.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: The images are just the database tables ,I can't sent the whole create/insert query

Comment: Why can't you update your question with sample input / expected output data? [Other people have managed to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714710/add-missing-data-from-previous-month-or-year-cumulatively#36714710). If you expect people to help you (for free, no less), it behooves you to provide as much information as possible, in a format that we can easily run ourselves. Data in an image (apart from the fact that not all of us can see the image due to firewall restrictions) requires effort on our parts to transcribe into something that can be tested against. Help us to help you.

Comment: Question... if you only select `dnumber` in your outer query (and not also the department name), why do you need to join with the `department` table? You don't. You do, however, if you want to include also the department name.

Comment: @boniest - it would help if the Forum had a document to which we can point new members. Not everyone knows how to use tools that exist in their client software to easily create DDL and DML statements for their tables (I don't think it's laziness or lack of interest, it's very likely lack of knowledge). This will help them in so many other ways, even outside this forum. I don't think such a document exists though, does it?

Comment: @mathguy not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dnumber as department_number,
       count(case de.relationship when 'SON'      then 1 end) as sons,
       count(case de.relationship when 'DAUGHTER' then 1 end) as daughters,
       count(case de.relationship when 'SPOUSE'   then 1 end) as spouses
from   [... the rest of your query here]
```

Comment: Solved the problem , I wasn't aware of the commands , thanks a lot

Comment: You may want to google for "Oracle CASE" and read about the case expression - it helps in many different scenarios, you will see it used often on SO if you have other problems in the future. Glad it helped!