# SQL conditional multiple inserts according to an attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables which already have data and a void relation table:

User(**idU**, idCreator, job, ...)

Permission(**idP**, name)

User_Permission(**idU#, idP#**, idCreator, ...)

---

For **each row** in User and **according to User.job value**, I would like to `INSERT INTO User_Permission VALUES(aPermID, idU, idCreator, ...)` where `idU is the own user's ID` and `idCreator is the User's ID creator`.

---

Example:

- If **User.job = 'Comm'**, I would `INSERT INTO User_Permission VALUES(100, User.idU, User.idCreator, ...)`.
- If **User.job = 'Dev'**, I would `INSERT INTO User_Permission VALUES(150, User.idU, User.idCreator, ...)` AND `INSERT INTO User_Permission VALUES(200, User.idU, User.idCreator, ...)`

---

I don't know how I can do that. I'm using Oracle, release 11g.

---

> **Clarification for idCreator attribute**
>
> Each user is created by another
>   one.  A `User_Permission` is also given by someone (that is why there is
>   an `idCreator` too).
>
> Here I am trying to recover old data, so by default I choose to make
>   `User_Permission.idCreator` same as `User.idCreator`.

Comment: Please update your question to provide some sample data to go along with your expected results so that we might have a chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Well, usually you'd either do it from whatever is inserting your `T1` records (or possibly via an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `T1`).  Why is `number` present in both tables?  Also, generally speaking, you shouldn't be using `id` for columns that must have a specific value (`100`, `150`), you should be using whatever the business/domain entity declares it as (which you might be doing anyways).

Comment: @Mistalis Not really. What is the data in USER and PERMISSION than generates the results you want to be inserted into USER_PERMISSION? I.e. why a single row with "100" for 'Comm' and two rows with "150" and "200" for 'Dev'? Please bear in mind that we can't see your data or tables, so you need to provide as much information about your situation as possible.

Comment: @Mistalis ([here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714710/add-missing-data-from-previous-month-or-year-cumulatively#36714710) of a question that provided decent sample data along with their expected output that allows us to see what they're working with and what they want to achieve)

Comment: User is a table I recovered from an old project. I would like to make inserts in User_Permission to give some defaults permissions to users according to there job. Some jobs can give several permissions (here `Dev` for example). But don't worry: a single row will be fine for me, can duplicate it (I have only 4 different permissions, I can make 1 request for each). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some table which maps job to Permid. Kind of

```
insert into User_Permission(idU#, idP#, idCreator, ...)
select map.permID, u.idU, u.idCreator, ...
from User u
join ( -- job class to permid mapping
    select  'Comm' class, 100 permID  from dual 
    union all
    select 'Dev', 150 from dual 
    union all
    select 'Dev', 200 from dual 
) map on map.class= u.job
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me!